# mysql_connect timing out

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I am trying to set up a PHP framework on my Mac 10.6 computer, and it keeps erroring during setup due to database connectivity issues. So I put together a small php script to see if I could connect to the server myself, and it couldn't either. The operation times out.

However, I am able to login to mysql from commandline perfectly fine. It's only PHP that is having these connection issues. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the script.

```
<?php
  $connection = mysql_connect("http://localhost", "root", "");
if( $connection ) {
  mysql_close( $connection );
  die('TRUE');
}else {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

EDIT: I tried removing http:// but then I get a "No such file error."

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Users/newuser/Downloads/t.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Users/newuser/Downloads/t.php on line 2
Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this :

```
mysql_connect("http://localhost", "root", "");
```

But your MySQL host is not `http://localhost` : it's probably `localhost`.

Try to remove that `http://`, using this :

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

*As a sidenote : working with the root account is not a good practice -- even on a development platform.*

----------

**EDIT after the comment :** In that case, try with `127.0.0.1` *(the IP address of `localhost`)*

And if you really want to use Unix sockets, you'll have to find which socket is used by your MySQL server *(it should be indicated in its configuration)* ; for instance, in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I have :

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then, you'll want PHP to use the same one :

- see the [`mysql.default_socket`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-socket) directive, about that,
- or pass it to [`mysql_connect()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) as a string such as `':/path/to/socket'`

Comment: I tried localhost but I get "No such file or directory error." Adding that to the post now.

Comment: @picardo : I'ev edited my answer, to give another hint, that should solve that problem -- using a TCP connection, instead of an Unix socket.

Comment: @pascal: the framework I'm installing uses http:// internally, though. So the script connects fine with 127.0.0.1, but the framework still fails...Do you know how I can make mysql_connect work with http://?

Comment: @picardo : re-edited to add something about sockets. Using `http` *(which is the protocol of the web)* feels very wrong, when it comes to connecting to a MySQL database, actually...

Comment: @pascal: I tried the my.cnf file method. Also edited my php.ini to point to `/tmp/mysql.socket` but none of them worked. (If you excuse me, I will proceed to bang my head on the wall now.)

Comment: Humph, sorry, I'm starting to get out of ideas :-( ; good luck with the wall, though ^^

Answer (score 1):

Take the "http://" out of the mysql_connect parameter. It wants a host, not an HTTP URL.

Comment: I tried localhost but I get "No such file or directory error." Adding that to the post now.

Comment: @picardo: Just because you encounter a problem with the correct approach, doesn't mean you should pick an obviously incorrect one instead! HTTP != MySQL. URL != host.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `http://` and use host name `localhost` only.

Answer (score 1):

Use "127.0.0.1" it will force using TCP4 insted of sockets.

If you want to use sockets, according to [this document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html) the default socket on Mac OS X is:

```
/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Fot this to be default you should edit your php confiuration or have an *.htaccess* file with:

```
php_value mysql.default_socket "/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

Comment: That worked. But do you know how to make it with sockets? The framework I'm installing -- Ushahidi -- connects through sockets, I think, and install keeps failing, which is why I was attempting this in the first place.